# Spring Boot Test Database Initialization runs twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am testing a Spring Boot Batch Application. I am using a in memory H2 DB that I would like to initialize with some data but its failing with a `Unique index or primary key violation: PRIMARY_KEY_7 ON ...`.

I have tried tweaking the `application.properties`, adding and removing

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=AD1
```

Also tweaking the `spring.datasource.url`.

The entity is as follows:

```java
@Table(schema = "ad1",name = "Student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private String studentId;

    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "favourite_subject")
    private String favouriteSubject;

    @Column(name = "enrollment_date")
    private LocalDate enrollmentDate;

}
```

To note is that the `schema` attribute has been set to `ad1`

`data-h2.sql` which lives in `src/test/resources` is as follows:

```sql
Insert into ad1.Student (student_id,student_name,favourite_subject,enrollment_date) values ('1151AB26','John','Math',to_date('01-JAN-19','DD-MON-RR'));
```

`application.properties` also in `src/test/resources` is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS AD1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=AD1
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

To note, is that `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS AD1`. I had to initialize the schema to AD1

I am using Cucumber so I have a a cucumber test class:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources", plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber" })
public class CucumberTest {

}
```

Last but not least the Spring boot test class

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StudentBatchApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration
public abstract class SpringCucumberIntegrationTest {
```

What happens is that when I start up the test I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_7 ON AD1.Student(student_id) VALUES ('1151AB26', 1)"; SQL statement:
Insert into AD1.Student (student_id,student_name,favourite_subject,enrollment_date) values ('1151AB26','John','Math',to_date('01-JAN-19','DD-MON-RR')) [23505-197]
```

When I troubleshoot this, by putting a break-point at the moment the initialization is happening, the process runs the same line twice:

```
( /* key:1 */ '1151AB26', 'John', 'Math', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
( /* key:2 */ '1151AB26', 'John', 'Math', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Right after this, it throws the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned, in the process of troubleshooting I noticed that the one line inside `data-h2.sql` was somehow being ran twice and hence giving this Unique index violation. Troubleshooting further, I traced back to the point in the process where it was loading the data script (ie. `data-h2.sql`) and noticed that it was loading this script twice. Once in `target\classes\data-h2.sql` and once in `target\test-classes\data-h2.sql`. I honestly don't know why this script file was being copied to `target\classes\data-h2.sql`.

In the end I found that this was an eclipse issue. When I ran the tests using command-line `mvn clean test`. The tests ran perfectly, but when I ran the tests with eclipse `Run As -> JUnit Test` I would encounter this problem. For some reason whenever I cleaned the application in eclipse `Project -> Clean` it copied all the resource files from `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` into `target\classes`. What I had to do was add the following line to my `.classpath` file.

```xml
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```